# :Noob Alert:Modern UI (Metro) Charts for Windows 8, WPF, Silverlight MySql

Tags: mysql

I need to use charts in my WPF application, and I found [Modern UI (Metro) Charts for Windows 8, WPF, Silverlight](http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) , i want to get the numbers from MySql and display a chart pie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a [Documentation](http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/documentation), it show you 'How to use the charts in your application'